# Android browsers support custom tabs

Tags: android, browser, android-customtabs

Any body have an idea which browsers supports Custom Tabs and from which version ?
I began the search today and i found that chrome, firefox, brave, edge all supports custom Tabs. any one did a search on this subject.

Custom Tabs is a browser feature which give apps more control over their web experience, and make transitions between native and web content more seamless without having to resort to a WebView.

thank you in advance

Comment: What is a custom tab?

Comment: Custom Tabs is a browser feature which give apps more control over their web experience, and make transitions between native and web content more seamless without having to resort to a WebView.
see https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: This is a perfectly clear question. Why was it closed?